# svn not recognized on Windows 10 with PhpStorm inside gulp.js

Tags: windows, svn, gulp, phpstorm, spawn

I´m trying to run svn command lines with a gulp task.
I tried the package [svn-spawn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svn-spawn) without success ; It seems to be not working on Windows.
So I tried [cross-spawn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-spawn) but I got this error :

> 'svn' is not recognized as an internal command line

But when I tried directly in the PhpStorm terminal `svn help`, I can see the list of options.

**gulpfile.js**

```
const spawn = require('cross-spawn');

gulp.task( 'publish',  function( callback ) {
   spawn( "svn", ["add", "trunk/*" ], { cwd: "publish/", stdio: "inherit" });
});
```

What can I do to run correctly a svn command to add and commit files on Windows 10 with a gulp task inside PhpStorm environment ?

Comment: looks like `svn` is not on your `%PATH%`; see if it is on your system `%PATH%` - system variables are system-wide accepted, so they should be available to all processes. See https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml for instructions on setting %PATH% system environment variable on Windows

Comment: @lena first of all, I´m trying to look for the `svn.exe` to know the path, but I did not find it.

Comment: When I run `svn info` I got this error > svn: E155007: '/home/user' is not a working copy

Comment: what terminal do you run it in? try running `where svn` command - what is the result?

Comment: looks as if you have it installed on WSL, right? It won't be available to gulp running in Webstorm then, you will need to run gulp from your bash shell

Comment: 'svn' is now recognized. The svn.exe is  in cywin/babun so I add the bin path. `where svn` helped me. The problem now is I get this error > svn: E155007: '/cygdrive/c/backup/path-to-my-project' is not a working copy

Comment: don't use SVN under cygwin, install a usual windows svn client instead